# Posts/Pages are not redirecting to Https when type it with http in addressbar?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Recently I have installed SSL on my site and redirected it from http://copybloggerthemes.com to https://copybloggerthemes.com

**Problem:** When I write the post url with http in address bar it does not redirect to https.

**Example:** This is my post: `http://copybloggerthemes.com/straight-blogger-template/`just copy this url and past it in address bar. You will see that it does not redirecting to https. You can check any post or page url like this.

**Note Also:** Only homepage works. When I enter this `http://copybloggerthemes.com` then it's redirecting to `https://copybloggerthemes.com` but not for posts and pages. Why?

I added this code in `.htaccess` file in bottom.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.copybloggerthemes\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://copybloggerthemes.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Now, I hope someone will help me in that regard. What mistake did I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you change your url in Settings > General tab where the WordPress Address (URL)  and Site Address is?

Comment: Ofcouse @dingo_d i did that you can see it here in screenshot.http://prntscr.com/d46lfv

Comment: Did you read articles on line that describe the protocol transfer, such as: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/ . Also, did you try to flush your permalinks?

Answer (score 1):

Use these rules in your HTACCESS file. This will handle both www and non-www URLs to be served over HTTPS. Moreover, the www version of the domain will be 301 redirected to non-www too.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# for non secure URLs without the www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your code is super one, it worked for me, i added it in .htacess file at the top and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This like should tell you how to set your site url in the template.  [Setting Wordpress Site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url)

Hope this helps.. Regards,  Tom

Comment: How to do that ? could you please explain me ?